# Register mobile number with WhatsApp using Yowsup and phone

Tags: yowsup

I have successfully registered a number with WhatsApp using Yowsup CLI like so:

Get the SMS:

```
python yowsup-cli registration --phone xxxxxxxxxxx --cc 1  -r sms
```

Register after getting the code:

```
python yowsup-cli registration --register xxx-xxx --phone xxxxxxxxxxx --cc 1
```

However, by doing so, it looks like it un-verifies the number from my phone.

Based on this link, it seems like there is a restriction on the WhatsApp side:
https://www.whatsapp.com/faq/en/general/21009863

Is there a way to associate a phone number in WhatsApp with Yowsup as well as a mobile device?

Answer (score 0):

Whatsapp only has a single-session thing. You won't have any way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

whatsapp don't allow you to have a single number at two diffrent places, but they allow you a temporary connection as we can see in the whatsapp web. anyway there is no way you can keep chatting and as well as use that paticular number for whatsapp too. my advice is to take a new number for yowsup because they might block you for running a bot